# Angular: recursive component for displaying a tree

Tags: angular

I have JSON-data that represents a tree-structure (data:string in app.component.ts).

Now I like to present the data in a table. For that I built foo.component.ts.
It prints one node and recusively goes ahead.

That is all working fine.

Here is it:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bqfh7h

But next I like to click on a node and mark every subnode of that node. Marking should be changing the font-weight in my sample.

That is not working and I am not sure why. I put the marking-action in the  because I think that includes every subnote.

Not sure if I did it wrong or that is not possible with recursive component.

Any idea to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've changed the structure slight;y of the component.

Each `foo` instance is now responsible for displaying it's name (i.e. `farm`), and the loop has moved so that it now loops through it's children. This way, there is a single parent, to many children.

I've also added an `@Input` for `selected`, which allows us to use binding to select the children.

**[Here is the working StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ybf9eu?file=src%2Fapp%2Ffoo.component.ts)**